# ask : memmove() and memcpy() on QT (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, memory

simple question, I have problem with memmove() and memcpy() when i'm using it. I really don't understand what wrong with my code. by the way i use QT.

```
HANDLE hFile;
HANDLE hMapFile;
HANDLE hMapView;

hFile = CreateFileW((const wchar_t*) objPath.constData(), GENERIC_READ , 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

    hMapFile = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    if (hMapFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){

        hMapView = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0,0);
        if (hMapView != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
            uint DefineWord;
            memmove((void *) &DefineWord, hMapView,2); // <- always error right here
            qDebug()<<DefineWord;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you were more explicit about what you're asking.  You have a comment, buried in your source code, saying "always error right here".  Please tell us exactly what the error is (is there an error message?), and provide that information in your question, not just in your source code.  Thanks.

Comment: In particular, are you getting an error when you compile your code, or when you run it?

Comment: when I debugging, there's a message "segmentation fault" SIGSEGV.

Comment: Do you have `#include <string.h>`?  Without that, the compiler can't see the declaration of `memmove` and can't necessarily diagnose calling it with the wrong type of argument (as Zan Lynx says, `hMapView` isn't a pointer).  But there should have been a compile-time warning; was there?

Comment: Of course i have #include <string.h>, and I also changed the declaration to be LPVOID hMapView. always the same error message occurs.

Comment: Then please update your question to show us both the current version of your code and the *exact* error message you're getting, clearly indicating which line in your source code it refers to.

Answer (score 1):

`hMapView` is not a pointer. `memmove` requires two pointers. Fix this by declaring hMapView properly. It should be a `LPVOID`.

Comment: I also changed the declaration to be LPVOID hMapView. always the same error message occurs. "segmentation fault" SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 1):

`MapViewOfFile` returns a pointer, or `NULL` (0) when there is an error, not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` (-1).

**Edit:** There was a lot of other problems with your code:

- `QString::constData()` returns `QChar*`, not `wchar_t*`, you have to use `QString::utf16()` instead.
- If `CreateFileMappingW` fails it returns `NULL`, not `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.
- `MapViewOfFile` access parameter is `FILE_MAP_READ`, not `GENERIC_READ`.
- `uint` is often bigger than 2 bytes, so you should initialize the variable to 0 before `memmove` if you only read 2 bytes.

Here is a minimal code that should work (only tested on wineg++/wine):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        QTextStream(stdout) << "Usage :" << argv[0] << " filename" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    QString objPath(argv[1]);
    // Qt source uses C-Style cast from utf16() to (wchar_t*),
    // so it should be safe
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW((const wchar_t *) objPath.utf16(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        qDebug() << qt_error_string(); 
    } else {
        HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMappingW(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
        if (!hMapFile) {
            qDebug() << qt_error_string(); 
        } else {
            void *pMapView = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
            if (!pMapView) {
                qDebug() << qt_error_string();
            } else {
                uint DefineWord = 0;
                memmove((void *) &DefineWord, pMapView, 2);
                qDebug() << DefineWord;
            }
            CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: `QString qt_error_string(int errorCode = -1)` is an apparently undocumented Qt function that returns the error string of the last error (from the error code returned from `GetLastError()` or `errno`).

If you are using Qt, you can map a file to memory with [QFile::map()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#map). 

To do what your initial code was supposed to do, you only had to add 2 lines to the code sample you found (plus the error checking):

```
QFile file("foo"); 
if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
   qDebug() << file.errorString();
} else {
    uchar *memory = file.map(0, file.size()); 
    if (!memory) {
        qDebug() << file.errorString();
    } else {            
        uint DefineWord = 0;
        memmove(&DefineWord, memory, 2);

        file.unmap(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to map a file with QFile::map().
But, I have some example code.

QFile file("foo");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
uchar *memory = file.map(0, file.size());
if (memory) {
// have some fun with the data
file.unmap();
}

Answer (score 0):

> by the way i use QT.

You aren't really using it in your example.
Qt has [QFile::map](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#map) method which can (and in my opinion should) be used instead of platform-specific MapViewOfFile.

Comment: Is that really an answer to the question, or should it be a comment?

Comment: @KeithThompson: If you dislike my answer, write your own. Using 3-deep level `if` instead of single line of code is counterproductive.

Comment: You may well be offering excellent advice (I'm not familiar enough with `MapViewOfFile` or `QFile::Map` to be sure of that).  I'm just not convinced that it's a direct answer to the question the OP is asking, which seems to be something like "Why am I getting an error in this code?"  If you can diagnose the problem *and* suggest a better solution, you'll have a great answer.